# Expanding silverlight combobox control upside?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox

Is there a way to change the expanding orientation to upside of a combobox control in silverlight instead of downside?

What i mean is think of youtube's video quality combobox its openning from bottom to top (the combo box to select 240p, 340p etc..).. If i put the combobox in the bottom of layout its openning upside as default but is there a way to achieve this in any other place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use a attached behaviour, since the Silverlight popup control of the ComboBox doesn't have the Placement property. A example of such behaviour can be found here: [Silverlight Popup with Target Placement](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2010/07/silverlight-popup-with-target-placement.html)

Then all you have to do is to apply a style, where you attach the behaviour to the Popup:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle1" TargetType="ComboBox">
    ... snip ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Grid>
                    ... snip ...

                    <!-- Attach behaviour here! -->
                    <Popup x:Name="Popup">
                        <Border x:Name="PopupBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" BorderThickness="0" Padding="1">
                                <ItemsPresenter/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!! It definitely gave me insight, and the link you gave me was excellent, but i was not able to achieve upside expanding popups. I implemented it as its in the link and your code but couldn't do it. Also i'm kinda suspicious that if there would be more than 1 items in combobox that the popup if it would expand over the actual combobox control itself.

Comment: You could always calculate the offset depending on the height of the combobox, so I wouldn't worry about that part.

Comment: Actually i was trying to escape that part and looking for a hack, but implementing my own attach behaviour seems like a much better choice in terms of readability and future use. I think i'll be doing that, thanks for the help Claus!